# How do I bind a column in a grid to a lookup table?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I am new to WPF, MVVM and EF and I want to develop an application using these technologies.

Simply lets say I have `Customer` and `Orders` tables in my DB.

I managed to generate the model using EF. I need a tutorial or example that enables me to learn how to do retrieve Customers and Orders in 2 grids and when selecting a customer it updates the ordergrid to get orders related to that customer.
I'd like to have add/update/delete in both grids.

How to bind a column in a grid to a lookup table?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/08/ef-feature-ctp5-code-first-model-with-master-detail-wpf-application.aspx

Comment: @Slauma i have seen this post while searching and its a good one but where's the mvvm pattern ,,u use drag and drop data binding,,and products is the child of catogory and it will be loaded via eager loading when loading customers. i have already did something like that and i dont want my application like that .

Comment: Doesn't the example use lazy loading (click on category -> products of category (virtual collection) get loaded)? But yes, there is no MVVM. Sorry, I don't know any better example :(

Comment: thnx so much @Slauma it helps me to get more into wpf..

Comment: @hatem: First off, I don't have an answer for you as I have never bound to a lookup table.  Second, we expect titles to be *titles*.  We have a tagging system and it works pretty good.  That's how I knew about your question--it came up in my MVVM RSS feed.  A title is not where you place tags; it is where you give everyone looking through the list of questions a good indication of what your question is about.  For more information about what a title is, [please read this question on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title).  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is exactly what you are looking for:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx#dataset

Under the section "Binding to a Dataset", the project uses a Customer table and an Order table, and shows examples of databinding.

**Edit**: I don't believe you need to install the WPF toolkit for the datagrid (as the tutorial claims), as it is included in WPF 4.

Comment: Thanks Tyrsuis for ur answer , i will check it and get back to u

Comment: I doubt that this is exactly what @hatem wants: The example uses neither Entity Framework nor the MVVM pattern.

Comment: @Slauma yes this is a gr8 article but it works on datasets not entity Framework and not using MVVM Pattern.